# I want to separate checkinout table import from zk attendance log in SQL

Tags: sql

I have connected zk attendance machine in SQL and import data. but in checkinout table its showing all in one column called checktime. I want to show 1st time as check in and and last time as check out in different columns. Date and time should be in different columns as well.

table name CHECKINOUT and column name checktime.

```
Select * from checkinout
```

Below is result of query

```
USERID      CHECKTIME
----------- -----------------------
1           2022-10-04 10:25:44.000
1           2022-10-04 10:25:46.000
1           2022-10-04 10:30:55.000
1           2022-10-04 11:39:23.000
2           2022-10-07 14:05:22.000
2           2022-10-08 09:19:58.000
2           2022-10-08 15:34:53.000
```

I want result like below

```
USERID      DATE                CHECKIN TIME       CHECK OUT TIME                                       
----------- -----------------------                                                        
1           2022-10-04          10:25:44.000       17:35
2           2022-10-04          10:25:46.000       17:40
```

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result. And also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: I have just updated on above please check im using SQL

Comment: Where does checkout time 17:25 for userid 1 come from? Does the expected result really match the given sample data?

Comment: What's expected to be returned if a user has checktimes for different dates? Or only one checktime for a date?

Comment: I need result check in time should be before 14:00 and checkout time after 14:01. i need looks like